# Reading Excel file from java servlet, no cells found

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

want to read a particular column and iterate the row.the code below does not give output(no error found).

```
while (rowIterator.hasNext())
{
    Row row = rowIterator.next();
    Cell cell=row.getCell(1);

    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
    while (cellIterator.hasNext()) 
    {
        cell = cellIterator.next();
        System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue());
    }
```

doesn't enters while loop!

Comment: Does your excel have any populated rows? Are you looking at the right sheet?

Comment: i have an excel sheet with data already in it.but i need to read only a particular column! say the 5th column.the problem is i m not able to get any method that fetch me the column.

Comment: what java to excel library are you utilizing?

Comment: which library you are using??

Comment: What is the code before this code?

Comment: `FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("johnson database.xlsx"));
      XSSFWorkbook workbook1 = new XSSFWorkbook(in);
      
      XSSFSheet sheet1 = workbook1.getSheetAt(1);
         Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet1.iterator();`

Comment: @user3134148 Could you change your loop to following and post the outcome here:
`while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
     Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
     switch (cell.getCellType()) {
     case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
      System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t");
      break;
     case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
      System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t");
      break;
     }
    }`

Comment: @PopoFibo the following code will work perfectly ,i have tried.but i need to work with a particular column not the entire sheet.

Comment: @user3134148 so it doesn't enter the Row iterator while loop or the cell one?

Answer (score 0):

`celliterator` is used for iterating all the cells within a row one by one. If you want to use  a particular column, you should not use `cellIterator`,

```
while (rowIterator.hasNext()){
    Row row = rowIterator.next();
    Cell cell=row.getCell(4); // for accessing 5th column
    System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue());
}
```

Please note that you have explicitely used `getNumericCellValue()` if you are not sure about this, you should use the same as suggested by  PopoFibo.